# Can data coming from different channels into select statement get ignored?

Tags: go, channel

Is it possible for data coming in through a channel in golang to get ignored if it is not caught at the right moment inside a select statement?

For example,  lets say there is this select statement:

```
for {
    select {
    case <-timer.C:
        //block A
    default:
        // block B takes 2 seconds.
    }
}
```

If timer ends while block B is running,  does block A still run in the next iteration of the loop or does the channel's incoming data get lost?

Comment: On the sending side, if it's a buffered channel with room then the data gets buffered. Otherwise it depends on if the writer blocks or not, and if it doesn't block if it retries or continues on and drops the data. The other way to drop/ignore data is for a reader to exit without ever reading buffered items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the timer expires, it will send the current time on C. If no one is reading from C at the time, the send will block, so it will wait until the value is received. In this case, it will wait till the next iteration of the loop.

Channels are designed to be  a synchronization mechanism, so they don't require readers and writers to be already synchronized.

Comment: Minor correction, `time.NewTimer` uses a buffered channel so that it cannot block. It will write the time into the buffer and either later someone reads it or, if the timer&channel are no longer referenced, they'll get garbage collected eventually.

Comment: Related, `time.NewTicker` also uses a channel with a buffer size of one and does non-blocking sends. It is documented as dropping ticks if the reader gets behind (if the buffer is already full the next tick gets dropped).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I didn't bother to look at the source to see whether the channel is buffered.

Comment: it's a minor implementation detail, your answer is still correct.